# Cannot load DataFrame with Phoenix/Spark

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have created a table in Phoenix called 'TEST' and I can query it from Phoenix and I can scan it in HBase's shell. I'm trying to use the Phoenix-Spark library as follows but the DataFrame is not filled:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.phoenix.spark._
val hadoopConf: Configuration = new Configuration()
val hbConf: Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create(hadoopConf)
val df = sqlContext.phoenixTableAsDataFrame("TEST", Array("foo", "bar"), conf = hbConf)
```

Instead, what I get is the following:

```
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(413840) called with curMem=0, maxMem=4445479895
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 404.1 KB, free 4.1 GB)
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(27817) called with curMem=413840, maxMem=4445479895
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 27.2 KB, free 4.1 GB)
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:39319 (size: 27.2 KB, free: 4.1 GB)
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from newAPIHadoopRDD at PhoenixRDD.scala:41
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x72187492 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=localhost:2181
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-2950--1, built on 09/30/2015 17:44 GMT
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=some.server.com
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_40
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_40/jre
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/conf/:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/hadoop-azure.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/azure-storage-2.2.0.jar
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=dude
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/dude
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/dude
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x721874920x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x25494c0cb650086, negotiated timeout = 40000
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO Metrics: Initializing metrics system: phoenix
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 60 second(s).
16/05/11 11:10:47 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: phoenix metrics system started
16/05/11 11:10:48 INFO RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0xd2eddc2 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=localhost:2181
16/05/11 11:10:48 INFO ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0xd2eddc20x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
16/05/11 11:10:48 INFO ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16/05/11 11:10:48 INFO ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
16/05/11 11:10:48 INFO ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x25494c0cb650087, negotiated timeout = 40000
16/05/11 11:11:36 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=48168 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/11 11:11:56 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=68312 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/11 11:12:16 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=12, retries=35, started=88338 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/11 11:12:36 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=13, retries=35, started=108450 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/11 11:12:56 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=14, retries=35, started=128530 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/11 11:13:16 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=15, retries=35, started=148547 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/11 11:13:37 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=16, retries=35, started=168741 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/11 11:13:57 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=17, retries=35, started=188856 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
```

I've found [this post](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/phoenix-user/201601.mbox/%3CCAN=qJ2Cq3c1Q3eOwxJZpCWfFoFNHBi34y1Y5ATUUfAE9bDoYqg@mail.gmail.com%3E), but I'm already using said method and passing the HBase configuration. What am I doing wrong?

Interestingly, my ZK quorom server is not localhost but a list of two servers even though it seems to show up as localhost in the INFO messages. I'm not sure if that's what it's supposed to show. The `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` parameter is properly set in `hbase-site.xml` and it's listed when I check `hbConf`. Moreover, `zookeeper.znode.parent` is set to `/hbase-unsecure` even though I see `/hbase` in the messages. Does Phoenix-Spark simply ignore those?!

I can use the HBase API directly but it would be nice to have Phoenix because I can immediately load the data as a DataFrame.

Answer (score 3):

Damn it! The mistake was that the column names should be capitalized. It would be nice though if Phoenix could tell me that the columns don't exist instead of waiting for nothing to happen. I'm filing this as a bug report!